# Alert/Confirm/popup handling in C# Selenium

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, browser-automation

I've searched at length for this, and none of the responses seem to apply
to quite what I'm seeing. We are using Selenium with C#

The problem is the inability to control alerts -- I think because they
disappear too quickly:

1) alerts/confirms appear on screen and then immediately disappear(but the alert doesn't disappear during manual execution), and

2) this causes an inability to be able to control the alert/confirm. I try
using SwitchTo().Alert().Accept() etc. but the program errors out saying no
alert is present, because it only appears for an instant then disappears.

Is there a way to make the alerts stay on screen and then let the program
continue execution so I can then use SwitchTo().Alert()?

Comment: If you already know how to switch frames off index, frame name, or Xpath, all you need is a quick iteration through all frames to search for the particular webelement.

Answer (score -1):

```
[TestClass]
public class UnitTest1
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod1()
    {
        IWebDriver _driver = new FirefoxDriver();

        _driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();

        _driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(new TimeSpan(0, 1, 0));

        _driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(@"file:///C:/Users/Kishore/Desktop/alert.html");

        _driver.FindElement(By.Id("btnAlert")).Click();

        _driver.SwitchTo().Alert().Accept();

        string output = _driver.FindElement(By.Id("output")).Text;

        Assert.AreEqual("Alert is gone.", output);

        _driver.FindElement(By.Id("btnPrompt")).Click();

        _driver.SwitchTo().Alert().SendKeys("Web Driver");

        _driver.SwitchTo().Alert().Accept();

        output = _driver.FindElement(By.Id("output")).Text;

        Assert.AreEqual("Web Driver", output);

        _driver.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! To make this answer useful, you should add some explanation about what this code does and how it solves OP's problem.